# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get rid of the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I have this snippet causing the issue:

```
const parent_lead_contact = this.props.parentLeads?.filter((lead) =>
      lead.contact_guid.includes(this.props.parent_lead_party_guid)
    );// This is an array which can be empty
    if (parent_lead_contact?.length > 0) {
      parent_lead_contact[0].is_parent_lead_contact = true;
    } else {
      parent_lead_contact.push({ is_parent_lead_contact: true }); //  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    }
```

Is there a proper way to get this? I am filtering data from a selector. Sometimes, the result would be an empty array. The important thing is that the selector is not returning `is_parent_lead_contact` property, but I have to add this property to the array regardless the array is empty.

Thanks a lot for spotting the issue.

Comment: `Sometimes, the result would be an empty array` ... and sometimes it seems, `this.props.parentLeads` is `undefined` - otherwise, why would you use `?.filter` rather than just `.filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an optional chain fails, everything past the `?.` is ignored, and the expression evaluates to `undefined`. So this line

```
const parent_lead_contact = this.props.parentLeads?.filter((lead) =>
      lead.contact_guid.includes(this.props.parent_lead_party_guid)
);// This is an array which can be empty
```

will not produce *an array that might be empty* - rather, it'll produce either an array that's been filtered, or `undefined`. That line should be changed to

```
const parent_lead_contact = this.props.parentLeads?.filter((lead) =>
      lead.contact_guid.includes(this.props.parent_lead_party_guid)
) ?? [];
```